# MySQL: Convert Date column to Year column

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table with `DATE` column. All the dates are valid i.e. no 0000-00-00. But we were in fact using only the year part of these dates. I tried changing the type of this column to `YEAR(4)`, I found following scenarios:

1. On my local system, MySQL version 5.5.37 via MySQL CLI, changing type retains the year.
2. On my local system, MySQL version 5.5.37 via Adminer, changing type retains the year.
3. Our internal DB server, MySQL version 5.0.46 via MySQL CLI, changing type retains the year.
4. Our internal DB server, MySQL version 5.0.46 via PhpMyAdmin, changing type retains the year.
5. Staging DB server, MySQL version 5.6.13 via PhpMyAdmin, dates in columns get converted to 0000.
6. Staging DB server, MySQL version 5.6.13 via MySQL CLI, dates in columns get converted to 0000.

What could cause these issues and how can I solve this? Currently we created a Rake task where we first create an additional column, copy existing column dates to new one, alter the column and copy just years back.

Edit: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html

Comment: what about adding another column, doing `UPDATE table SET year=YEAR(date_column)` then deleting the old column ? Can't really say why that's happening.

Comment: That's the crux of my question, Why is it happening? I have edited my post and added a link from MySQL doc but I am still stumped. BTW, I described how I handled it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` 
CHANGE `columnName` `columnName` YEAR
```

This returns you 0000 in phpmyadmin. You should create a new column and rename it and then delete the old one.

Comment: I have already done that. My question is more related to how can retain column data by changing column's data type.

Comment: I request you to make an effort before posting a question or search relavent questions.

Comment: Thank you. You can delete and refrain from answering if you do not wish to read and understand questions. Nobody asked you to. Plus I didn't mean that sarcastically. Do not just assume that other people know nothing. BTW the answer you posted is incorrect usage of MySQL ALTER commands.

Answer (score 0):

The `YEAR(2)` data type has certain issues that you should consider before choosing to use it.

```
As of MySQL 5.6.6, YEAR(2) is deprecated.
```

YEAR(2) columns in existing tables are treated as before, but YEAR(2) in new or altered tables are converted to YEAR(4).

Read more here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-13.html

Comment: I was using `YEAR(4)`, I will update this in my post as well. Th problem is while converting from `DATE` to `YEAR(4)`